# How can i write ( draw string ) on ImageSource?

Tags: silverlight

I have some simple ImageSource.

I want to 'draw' some string every 20 pixels and show the result on the Image control.

In simple WPF i did it by using Graphics (  using ( Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage( imgTarget ) ) )

But in silverlight i can't use Graphics.

So, How can i do it in silverlight ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use [`WriteableBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx).  There is one caveate, tho. If you get an image from an external link into `WriteableBitmap`, you won't be able to alter it due to security restrictions placed on the class.

WriteableBitmap is a bit primative, so i would recommend the [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) library on codeplex. It is a really nice extention library for `WriteableBitmap` that gives you things like Bliting and shapes and transformations, etc.

[Edit]
As suggested by @Samvel Siradeghyan, you should (probably) use the code [here](http://www.smartypantscoding.com/content/rendering-text-writeablebitmap-silverlight-3s-bitmap-api) to render text to your `WriteableBitmap`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class.
You can find simple code about how to do that here: [Rendering Text to a WriteableBitmap with Silverlight 3's Bitmap API](http://www.smartypantscoding.com/content/rendering-text-writeablebitmap-silverlight-3s-bitmap-api)
Other solution is in [http://forums.silverlight.net](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/17039/56621.aspx) (not as good as in first article).